# Autoconversion in javascript: Isn't it supposed to convert a string to a number when done like stringvar = 1+stringvar?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

(Firefox32, Win 7)

When using the scratchpad:

```js
var a = "2";
a = 1 - 1 + a;
console.log(a, typeof a);

a = 1 + a - 1;
console.log(a, typeof a);
```

leads in the console to:

```
"02" "string"
101 "number"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm sure I have converted strings to numbers that way very often, and it worked. (Though I like to use the explicit converting functions much more, but as it worked so flawlessly for so long, ... :/  )

And why is the third line a number? But not the second? And why is it 101?

Comment: no. 1 + "2" === "12" &&  "1" + 2 === "12"

Comment: 3rd is number because minus is the first thing that happens. "2" - 1 === 1 (minus does convert to Number because it's not used with strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't it supposed to convert a string to a number when done like stringvar = 1+stringvar?

Nope. :-) If **either** operand is a string, it's string concatenation, not addition. This is defined by [§11.6.1 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) in Step 7:

> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
> 6. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
> 7. If Type(lprim) is String ***or*** Type(rprim) is String, then
>
>    1. Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim). See the Note below 11.6.3.

*(My emphasis on "or")*

Re your third example, `1 + a - 1` where `a` is `"02"`:

```
1 + "02" - 1
```

The addition (binary `+`) and subtraction (binary `-`) operators have the same precedence and both are left-to-right associative, so that's performed like this:

```
(1 + "02") - 1    =>    "102" - 1    => 101
```

The `+` is string concatenation, but since the [subtraction operator `-`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) **always** works with numbers, it coerces the `"102"` to `102` before subtracting `1` from it to get `101`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how string concatenation works.

> ```
> // Number + String -> concatenation
> 5 + "foo" // "5foo"
> ```
>
> – [MDN's Addition Operator usage examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_(.2B))

You can get around this by using the [Unary Plus operator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)) to avoid having to call `parseInt`:

```
a = 1 + +a;
```

> ### Unary plus (`+`)
>
> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number.

Comment: @John: Because it's not possible to subtract strings, so it implicitly converts the operands to numbers.

Comment: @John because `string - number` is converted to a number. `1 + "02"` is `"102"`. `"102" - 1` is `101`.

Comment: @John: No, it doesn't have anything to do with `charCodeAt`. `1 + "02" - 1` is done like this (clearer version in my answer): `(1 + "02") - 1` => `"102" - 1` => `101` because addition/concatenation and subtraction have the same precedence and both are left-to-right associative, and subtraction is always subtraction and so coerces its operands to numbers.