# Should YouTube api width, height values be in quotes or not?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

What does the youtube javascript api say about whether or not 
'width' and 'height' values should be in quotes or not?

I'm seeing it written both ways.

Here it shows one in quotes, then another that isn't in quotes:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Which should it be?

Which would be the correct, or right syntax to use and why?

https://jsfiddle.net/4nm15xzk/13/

```
new YT.Player(video, {
      width: 606,
      height: 344,


new YT.Player(video, {
      width: "606",
      height: "344",
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). In the examples it states `height` and `width` as quoted strings, in examples it uses both strings and numbers. Most likely it accepts both ways for convenience. Either it supports explicitly in source code of player library, or relays on implicit conversion. Here is an article [JavaScript type coercion explained](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839) that explains implicit conversion. Here is [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128170/1556857) discussing mathematics on mixed types with reference to specification.

Comment: But it shows it using both. Up top is quotes, towards the bottom it's no quotes. 1.) height: '390', / width: '640', / 2.) width: 1280, height: 720,

Comment: Then it is either accepts both for convenience, or relays on implicit conversion. Here is good article that explains it https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839. In JavaScript world it is all around like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of having a mess in docs. Since it's pretty obvious the API accepts both, I'd use whatever feels right in context of *my* code. I'd use numbers as they'll probably be calculated somehow. This way, I'll save myself from doing an unnecessary cast to a string.

Answer (score 0):

for number as value it is not necessary to be in quotes or not except your are doing strict comparison `===` / `!==`

```js
let yt = {width: "606"}
console.log(yt['width'])
console.log(yt['width'] * 2)
console.log(yt['width'] == 606)
console.log(yt['width'] === 606)

console.log("\n")
yt = {width: 606}
console.log(yt['width'])
```